# Multiple craft.entries field parameters

Tags: entries, entries-field, params

I have an for entry loop in which I need to look for two different field conditions. Separately they are:

```
craft.entries.eventStartDate('>=' ~ (now.date))

craft.entries.genericEventDate(':notempty:’)
```

How can I ask craft to look to see if **either** of these parameters is true?

**Update**

A work around is to pull the query without these paramaters and then run an if statement like:

`{% if entry.eventStartDate >= now.date or entry.genericEventDate is not empty %}`

This works but it's not really ideal since the query is pulling more entries than necessary.

Answer (score 3):

The only possible core solution to query for these entries in Twig is to query for entry IDs first, process them with [`merge`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/merge.html) or [`without`](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/filters#without) and then pass the IDs to the `id` parameter of a new ElementCriteriaModel.

Other than your solution implementing a conditional in the for loop this works with `paginate` and `getNext` tags, you only query for the entry models you're after, but the cost of this is the extra queries you need to get the IDs.

```
{% set futureEventsIds = craft.entries.eventStartDate('>=' ~ (now.date)).ids() %}
{% set specialEventsIds = craft.entries.genericEventDate(':notempty:').ids() %}
{% set idParam = futureEventsIds|merge(specialEventsIds) %}

{% set allEvents = craft.entries.id(idParam).order('GREATEST(eventStartDate, genericEventDate) desc') %}
```

Answer (score 2):

Hmm, I can't think of how you would do this in Twig. But you may want to jump into PHP and perform your query a little more manually... [This answer](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/723/45) provides a few good ways to do that.

Specifically, I'd take a look into either a [custom variable](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/variables) or a [template hook](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/services/TemplatesService#hook-detail). I'm personally a huge fan of the **template hook**... it feels like unlimited power in a tiny package.

Once you're in PHP, you can use Craft's `buildElementsQuery` along with Yii's `DbCommand` to generate your own complex query. For a rough example, check out [this question and answer...](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/q/2786/45)

Comment: I'm with you with this option but is it too much to ask to do this inline as just a part of the craft.entries query?

Comment: Agreed, a Twig-based solution would be preferred. But I don't have one, so I figured I'd leave you with this alternate approach instead. :)

Answer (score 1):

Many years later - a solution by pulling the queries separately, then merging the arrays and sorting them. Docs [here](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/sort.html)

```
{% set events      = craft.entries().section('events').theMainCategory(entry.id).orderBy('startDate asc').all() %}
{% set eventsOther = craft.entries().section('events').otherCategories(entry.id).orderBy('startDate asc').all() %}
{% set events      = events|merge(eventsOther) %}
    
{% for event in events|sort((a,b) => a.startDate <=> b.startDate) %}
    {# Display event #}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong here as only just started learning Craft and its template system but would this not work?

```
{% if (

    craft.entries.eventStartDate|date('U') >= now|date('U')
    or
    craft.entries.genericEventDate != ""
)
%}

<p>Show this text!!</p>

{% endif %}
```