# 'Unknown error' caused by redirect in htaccess

Tags: error, htaccess

I was getting an 'unknown error' when trying to access the admin. I couldn't see anything in the Craft logs apart from 404 related errors.
I replaced the app folder but still no luck, eventually I discovered it was a rewrite rule in my `.htaccess` causing the problem.

```
# redirect PHP or HTM to no extension
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^\ ]+)\.(php|htm?)
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,R=301]
```

I'd love to understand why, and how I can get around this in the future?

Comment: Out of interest - why are needing to do this? Craft can handle this for you.

Comment: I didn't know it could! Can you point me to where to look?

Comment: It won't handle it per say but the convention when building a Craft site is to generally not use `php` files (http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/722/can-we-use-php-in-our-templates-instead-of-twig). For `htm` you can just rename these to `html` and the extension will be removed automatically if placed in the `template` directory.

Answer (score 2):

It might be down to the order you have the code in your htaccess file? Did you try putting your code above the Craft rewrite code?

```
# redirect PHP or HTM to no extension
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^\ ]+)\.(php|htm?)
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,R=301]

# Send would-be 404 requests to Craft
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(favicon\.ico|apple-touch-icon.*\.png)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.+) index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Also I tend to exclude certain directories when I don't want rewrites to apply. One way to do this would be;

```
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# | Exclude directories from the rewrite rules                                 |
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
RewriteRule ^craft - [L]
```