# EmailModel - Unexpected character "$"?

Tags: emails

This is probably a newby question, but, I am just trying to add a basic email send test and my twig page does not like the dollar signs.  Is EmailModel built-in to craft or is there a plugin I need?

I am just trying to add this code to a basically empty twig page:

```
$email = new EmailModel();
$email->subject = "Thanks!";
$email->htmlBody = "<h1>Congratulations!</h1";
$email->htmlBody .= "<p>Hello World</p>";
$email->fromEmail = "email@domain.com";
```

thanks for the help...

Chip

Comment: You're adding PHP to a Twig page? Unless I'm missing something, that fundamentally doesn't make sense. Can you show us _how_ you've added this to your Twig code?

Comment: I am transitioning from a C#/.net background to a CraftCMS/Twig/PHP platform, so, I recognized that this didn't seem to make sense, but, I couldn't find a way to easily integrate an email process into my Craft CMS site (built of twig pages) and this was the only code I have found so far.  What is the best way to do this: When a user hits a button on the site, I want a pdf file to be attached and emailed to an email address that was typed into a text box on that page.

Comment: You probably answered the question that I brought up.  I will ask my more general question as a new question. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use [PHP in a Twig template](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/722/can-we-use-php-in-our-templates-instead-of-twig).

A plugin Craft plugin would be the easiest way to pull off what you're looking for.  I've added an answer to your other [related question](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/19861/what-is-the-best-way-to-generate-email-messages-with-attachments-from-twig-files).