# What is the best way to generate email messages with attachments from Twig files?

Tags: emails

I am coming from a .net/C# background and we have recently moved to a Craft/Twig platform.  What is the best way to do this: Have a visitor come to a Craft webpage (Twig file), enter their email address in a text box, hit a button, and have an email message sent to them containing a PDF attachment that they selected from that page?

Is this functionality built-in to Craft or do I need a plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a simple [Craft plugin](https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/introduction).  You can generate the boilerplate plugin code [here](https://pluginfactory.io).

Your form on the front-end will set its hidden action input to your plugin's [controller's](https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/controllers) [action](https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/controllers#posting-to-controller-actions).

From there, you can use Craft's [EmailModel](https://craftcms.com/classreference/models/EmailModel) (along with [`addAttachment()`](https://craftcms.com/classreference/models/EmailModel#addAttachment-detail)) and [EmailService](https://craftcms.com/classreference/services/EmailService)'s [`sendEmail()`](https://craftcms.com/classreference/services/EmailService#sendEmail-detail) to send whatever email contents you wish.

Comment: I just spent a few days going through Mijingo's Craft Plugin Course.  So, I can now attack this and see if I can make it work.

Comment: Does addAttachment work ok on local host urls?  I have the following: 
$pubpath = /localhost:3000/uploads/pubfiles/Lampen2014.pdf   .................                    
$email->addAttachment($pubpath); ................                          
Email error: Could not access file: //localhost:3000/uploads/pubfiles/Lampen2014.pdf

Comment: As I typed I realized I needed to remove the localhost from the path to /uploads..... etc... and it works fine.  Now I just need to remove the first part, is there a quick truncate left method or something like that?  Thanks!