# PHP eval filter for Twig

Tags: twigextension

If I am confident in the users of our webpage that they will never be messing with the Twig templates, then what risk is there to creating a `|php` filter for Twig that just does this?

```
{% set text = "echo 'Hello World';" %) 
{{ text | php }}
```

Filter function:

```
function myPhpEvalFunction ($text = null) {
   return eval($text);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Craft 3 it is actually possible.

```
{{ craft.app.view.evaluateDynamicContent('phpinfo();') }}
```

See: [Can we use PHP in our templates instead of Twig?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/722/can-we-use-php-in-our-templates-instead-of-twig)

Comment: My god... what have I done? :)

Comment: Only because you can, doesn't mean you should :)